# How do I include pthread.h file in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, pthreads

I use Mingw gcc(in Eclipse) but I am not able to use pthread.h library.
So I am getting this error:"fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory".So please suggest me some way to get rid of it.